# MySQL: Current Week To Date from Last Year

Tags: mysql

I am currently attempting to obtain the Week to Date value from Last Year based on the day of the week (let's assume it's Wednesday).  Here is what I have for obtaining Week to Date for this year which works flawlessly:

```
SELECT Dealership, 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEARWEEK(activity_date,1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(),1) THEN Sales END)
FROM MasterDB
GROUP BY Dealership;
```

I've read up on DateAdd or SUBDATE but am still currently stumped.  Any assistance?

EDIT:

Table Structure is as follows:

```
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    | activity_date | Dealership |  Sales |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2021-04-26  |    Ford    | $1,200 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2021-04-27  |    Ford    |  $900  |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2021-04-26  |    Dodge   | $1,600 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2021-04-27  |    Dodge   | $1,300 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2020-04-27  |    Ford    | $2,400 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2020-04-28  |    Ford    | $2,700 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2020-04-27  |    Dodge   | $3,400 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
    |   2020-04-28  |    Dodge   | $2,400 |
    +---------------+------------+--------+
```

For the example, it is Wednesday today, therefore my Week to Date for Ford this year is $2,100 ($1,200 + $900).  My Week to Date for last Year for Ford is $5,100 ($2,400 + $2,700)

Comment: I don't understand "Week to Date value from Last Year"; can you explain more *and* give several examples?

Comment: so you want to look at the previous year data, for the same week number, only up to the same day of the week, right?

Comment: I've edited the post to show the table structure of the data.  Both your answers do not appear to be ending in the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty straightforward way to get the sales data for the same week the previous year. I don't think this is what you are asking for though:

```
SELECT Dealership, SUM(Sales)
FROM MasterDB
WHERE YEAR(activity_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 AND
      WEEK(activity_date,1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1)
GROUP BY Dealership;
```

What you are asking for, though, is that it only includes up to the same day, so if today is Wednesday, you want the sales Monday-Wednesday last year. Well, that's just one more condition:

```
WEEKDAY(activity_date) <= WEEKDAY(CURDATE())
```

Using WEEKDAY means Monday=0, so it works nicely with your example of starting the week on monday. Put it together:

```
SELECT Dealership, SUM(Sales)
    FROM MasterDB
    WHERE YEAR(activity_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 AND
          WEEK(activity_date,1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1) AND
          WEEKDAY(activity_date) <= WEEKDAY(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY Dealership;
```

EDIT: Considerations:
If performance is a consideration, this solution isn't ideal for using an index on the activity_date. To do that, you'd need to calculate the start and end date based on CURDATE() and then compare to activity_date directly.

If activity_date is a TIMESTAMP you really have to take timezones into account.

Comment: This appears to still be considering the entire week, rather than the week-to-date position.  Ultimately, if it is Wednesday, I am looking for Monday & Tuesday only from that week so far.  Edit:  I removed the ,1 from the WEEK(activity_date,1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1) and it appears to be working now.

Comment: the WEEKDAY would limit it. I used `<=` to get Monday-Wed. If you want just Monday and Tuesday, use `<` instead.  The "1" argument to WEEK should be necessary, otherwise you are matching a SUNDAY-SATURDAY week instead of a MONDAY-SUNDAY week.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same week as the current week, but for the previous year, I think you need to do something complex like:

```
WHEN YEARWEEK(activity_date,1) = CONCAT(LEFT(YEARWEEK(CURDATE(),1),4)-1,RIGHT(YEARWEEK(CURDATE(),1),2))
```

Be aware that different years have different numbers of weeks, so sometimes there will be no corresponding week in the previous year.